# Are applications such as image processing naturally slow in Scheme for lacking a random-access data-structure?

Tags: data-structures, scheme

Scheme lists are slow for random access, which is a common operation in many applications such as image processing. Does this make it naturally handicapped for that kind of application?

Answer (score 5):

If performance is a concern, then you should definitely consider using fixed-access-time structures. Fortunately, Scheme has lots of these, too. The "vector" is the simplest one; it's a close match to what most languages call an "array".

Comment: Unless in a strongly typed variant, vector is usually represented internally as an array of pointers, and an array of pointers to integers, just isn't going to be as fast as an array of integers, as the array on integer is going to be loaded into cache in large chunks, reducing cache misses as compared to the first method.

Comment: @WorBlux First, this quote (from Jon Bentley?): "Premature Optimization is the root of all evil." Don't pay the high price of wrestling with details like this until you're absolutely positive that it's a performance problem. With that said: languages like Racket allow you to have your cake and eat it too, with typed vectors and arrays that bytecode compile to perform this optimization.